# Does Python define the value of "NaN > 0"?

Tags: python, nan, comparison-operators

Does Python defined the value of "NaN > 0"? In my Python interpreter, I get:

```
>>> float('nan') > 0
False
```

but is this guaranteed?

If I understand correctly, the IEEE 754 standard assigns [False to any comparison involving NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Floating_point). However, I can't find anything in the Python documentation that indicates that this standard is followed. I even understand that `1/0` should give infinity, under IEEE 754, but Python raises an exception (`ZeroDivisionError`), so Python does not fully follow IEEE 754.

So, is the result of `float('nan') > 0` fully defined in Python? I need to know whether it is the same on all platforms, and with all versions of Python (including old ones).

Comment: I think NaNs in Python are underdocumented. It's sort of implied they are IEEE 754, but doesn't seem to be explicitly mandated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Python implementations that I've used on various platforms use IEEE-754 and would behave as you describe.

However, this does not appear to be formally mandated by the language. So much so that the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) has the following to say (emphasis mine):

> *Almost* all machines today (July 2010) use IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic, and *almost* all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision”.

Here is a relevant thread from 2008: [Python on non IEEE-754 platforms: plea for information](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Python-on-non-IEEE-754-platforms-plea-for-information-td1863277.html).

It is very easy to check whether your interpreter/platform behave the way you expect. If you're critically dependent on this, you could easily detect non-compliance when your program starts up.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a pretty safe assumption.  The [`math` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan) documentation *implies* that python's `NaN` *should* act as specified in IEEE 754.

Of course, if you're really paranoid about it, you could write a UnitTest and then if you ever do find a system where that doesn't hold, at least you'll know immediately.

Comment: The math library does not imply much more than does the very existence of `float('nan')` in Python… The question is really about *how much* support there is for NaN, including in the definition (or not) of the result of `NaN > 0`. I think that NPE nailed it down: it is official that full support is not guaranteed.

Comment: @EOL -- That's not how I read it.  "for more information about NaN, consult IEEE 754".  To me, that says, NaN acts like it does in IEEE 754.

Comment: Fair enough. However, I understand that NaN *is an IEEE 754 concept*, so IEEE 754 is implicitly referred to by `float('nan')`, no?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/) suggests that, the NaN concept was incorporated in python from version 2.3. So it should be same on all platforms in the currently used versions.

It also has an implementation in [math](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan) library.

e.g. `math.isnan()`

```
Checks if the float x is a NaN (not a number).
NaNs are part of the IEEE 754 standards. Operation like but not limited to
inf * 0, inf / inf or any operation involving a NaN, e.g. nan * 1, return a NaN.


New in version 2.6.

>>> import math
>>> x=float('nan')
>>> math.isnan(x)
True
>>>
```

Comment: The real question is how IEEE 754-compliant Python is… NPE's answer is quite precise: IEEE 754 is not mandated by the language.